# Mdl components not working when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

I am making an onclick function and then displaying the progress bar by appending it from javascript. 
I am also using the material design lite cdn.
The components get added but dosen't show up on UI.

Code for progress Bar

```js
var pageContent = document.getElementById("page-content")
    var progressBar = document.createElement("div")
    progressBar.classList.add("mdl-spinner")
    progressBar.classList.add("mdl-js-spinner")
    progressBar.classList.add("is-active")
    progressBar.id = "pBar"
    pageContent.appendChild(progressBar)
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added the javascript into the contents of your page: `<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>`

This script makes the `componentHandler` available to be called from your javascript.  Call this each time you've added elements to the dom.

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom()
```

or individually upgrade each element as [documented](https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic), adding a call to `upgradeElement` after you dynamically append any child elements to the dom:

```
var progressBar = document.createElement("div")
    progressBar.classList.add("mdl-spinner")
    progressBar.classList.add("mdl-js-spinner")
    progressBar.classList.add("is-active")
    progressBar.id = "pBar"
    pageContent.appendChild(progressBar)
    componentHandler.upgradeElement(progressBar); //<- add this call
```

Comment: i have that cdn in html document, do you mean i need to add that into my js file too ?

Comment: Yes, you must.  Perhaps my edits will help clarify.

Comment: @DhruvAggarwal you have to call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` on each and everytime you add an mdl-element using javascript

Answer (score 1):

***Try this***

*Just add this code after material components are added.*

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```